# How to fix query to get wrong answers

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file and I need to filter to get "Wrong" answers. My query only executes when first answer has value Wrong. And it does not filter the results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Test>
  <BA_Part_I>
    <Q _001="A"></Q>
    <Q _002="C"></Q>
    <Q _003="B, D"></Q>
    <Q _004="2, 4, 9"></Q>
    <Q _005="A"></Q>
    <Q _006="2, 6, 7, 4, 8"></Q>
    <Q _007="A"></Q>
    <Q _008="C"></Q>
    <Q _009="A">Wrong</Q>
    <Q _010="D"></Q>
    <Q _011="C"></Q>
    <Q _012="1, 3"></Q>
    <Q _013="B, D"></Q>
    <Q _014="B"></Q>
    <Q _015="B"></Q>
    <Q _016="A, F">Wrong</Q>
    <Q _017="A"></Q>
    <Q _018="D"></Q>
    <Q _019="3, 1, 1, 2"></Q>
    <Q _020="B"></Q>
    <Q _021="A, B"></Q>
  </BA_Part_I>
</Test>

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

//...
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("Tracker.xml"));

        var query1 = from q in document.Descendants("BA_Part_I")
                        where q.Element("Q").Value == "Wrong"
                        select q;

        foreach (var item in query1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

I also tried to change query to list it still didn't work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LINQ query used for selection is incorrect. Use this to extract the nodes that have the value "Wrong" in them

```
var query1 = from q in document.Descendants("BA_Part_I").Descendants("Q")
                     where q.Value == "Wrong"
                     select q;`
```

Note that we are picking up the Descendants("Q") within the BA_Part_I node and then checking the Value of the node.